# Seg Fault with Prefix

Tags: c++, unix, prefix, fault, infix-notation

I am getting a segmentation fault when trying to convert an infix expression into prefix order. I have a postfix using the same logic that works fine the issue seems to be where i try to read the infix expression in reverse but I am not exactly sure why it is faulting. Any help would greatly appreciated Here is the relevant code:

```
int ParseTree::prefix(string infix)
{
        vector<string> exp;
        stringstream ss(infix);
        string tok;

        while(getline(ss,tok,' '))
        {
                exp.push_back(tok);
        }
        vector<string> prefix;
        stack<string> s;

        for(unsigned int i = exp.size() - 1; i >= 0 ; i--)
        {
                if(parseTry(exp[i]))
                {
                        prefix.push_back(exp[i]);
                }
                if(exp[i] == "(")
                {
                        s.push(exp[i]);
                }
                if(exp[i] == ")")
                {
                        while(!s.empty() && s.top() != "(")
                        {
                                prefix.push_back(s.top());
                                s.pop();
                        }
                        s.pop();
                }
                if(isOperator(exp[i]) == true)
                {
                        while(!s.empty() && priority(s.top()) >= priority(exp[i]))
                        {
                                prefix.push_back(s.top());
                                s.pop();
                        }
                        s.push(exp[i]);
                }
        }
        while(!s.empty())
        {
                prefix.push_back(s.top());
                s.pop();
        }

        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < prefix.size(); i++)
        {
                cout << prefix[i] << " ";
        }
        return 0;
}
int ParseTree::priority(const string &s)
{
        if(s == "*" || s == "/")
        {
                return 2;
        }
        if(s == "+" || s == "-")
        {
                return 1;
        }
        else
        {
                return 0;
        }
}

bool ParseTree::parseTry(const string &s)
{
        bool number = false;
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
        {
                if(!isdigit(s[i]))
                {
                        number = false;
                }
                else
                {
                        number = true;
                }
        }
        return number;
}

bool ParseTree::isOperator(const string &s)
{
        return (s == "+" || s == "-" || s == "*" || s == "/");
}
```

Comment: `unsigned int >= 0` will **always** be true, your compiler might be able to warn you about this if you turn warnings on.

Comment: I changed it to int > 0 and it still faults.

Comment: Use a debugger or post an [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your `parseTry` is equivalent to `return isdigit(s[s.size()-1])`. You need to return when you find an error, not keep looping.